# Javascript - Protractor - Clicking a checkbox terms & conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, protractor

I'm very fresh to the angular testing and please help to write the protractor angular e2e testing code to below term and condition checkbox.

create profile button will be enable when the check box is clicked only.

```html
//when clicked the checkbox

<md-checkbox ng-model="terms" aria-label="Terms &amp; Conditions" required="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" class="md-checked ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" aria-required="true" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="md-container md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="md-icon"></div><div class="md-ripple-container"></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="md-label"><span class="ng-scope">
          I agree to example</span><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/" class="ng-scope">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </div></md-checkbox>    
  
  
  
  
//when not clicked the checkbox
 
<md-checkbox ng-model="terms" aria-label="Terms &amp; Conditions" required="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" class="ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" aria-required="true" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="true" style=""><div class="md-container md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="md-icon"></div><div class="md-ripple-container"></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="md-label"><span class="ng-scope">
          I agree to example </span><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/" class="ng-scope">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </div></md-checkbox>
```

Comment: @Gunderson
I did is ,
 var check = element(by.css('md-ripple-container'));
 expect(check.isSelected()).toBe(false);
 check.click();
 expect(check.isSelected()).toBe(true);

Answer (score 0):

You have to simulate the click on the checkbox, then write an assertion, in this example the assertion is the `ng-valid` class on your element.

```
describe('Validate terms and conditions', () => {
  it('should accept terms and conditions', (done) => {
    browser.get('/#/transfert');

    const checkbox = element(by.model('terms'));
    checkbox.click().then(() => {
      expect(checkbox.getAttribute('class').to.equal('ng-valid'))
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this with copy paste to my code. but errors. please help

Comment: @Mpf "copy paste to my code but errors" means nothing. Please be sure to report the errors you had in order to allow the user to properly help you

Answer (score 0):

In the e2e tests actually you simulate users actions, in order to see if your application responds as expected. So here the flow you should follow:

```
let checkboxElement = element(by.model('terms'));
let createProfileButtonElement = element(by.id('my-id-create-profile-button'));
checkboxElement.click().then((data) => {
  expect(createProfileButtonElement.isEnabled()).to.become(true);
  // done() callback of the it block
});
```